# Number of nodes of value x in subtree of node s?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, hashmap

> **We are given a rooted tree where each node has some value.**
>
> **Our task is to process queries that ask to calculate the number of nodes with value x in the subtree of node s.**

We can also use the **offline algorithm** as there are no **update queries**.
So we can read all queries at once then process them in any order.

**Naive approach**: For each query **count(node s, val x)**, start a ***DFS*** from the node **s**, count the number of nodes with value **x** in it.

> **Pseudocode**:

```
DFS(node s, int v): 

    if(!s) return 0;

    cnt = 0;
    if(s.val == v) 
        cnt += 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.children.size; i++) {
        cnt += DFS(s.children[i], v);
    }

    return cnt;
```

> **Complexity**:

For **Q** number of queries, time complexity **O(Q * N)**, where **N** is number of nodes in tree.

> **How can I answer the queries efficiently?**

Comment: Will the space complexity of O(n^2) work?

Comment: Return a map of values from child?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes that approach will take O(n^2) space.

Comment: @YashShah Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Yash Shah, But to build O(n^2) space, time complexity would also be O(n^2), right?

Comment: @tusharRawat No that will be time complexity will be O(n).

Comment: @vivek_23 , you're saying we need to maintain a map like DS for each node of tree? What would be the time complexity of that approach?

Comment: @vivek_23 think about the skewed tree.

Comment: @YashShah, can you elaborate the approach, how is it going to be O(n) time?

Comment: @tusharRawat Recursively visit each node from root returning a map.

Comment: @tusharRawat Return a map of values from each child and now have a new map for each node. Have the node have this returned map of values in this new map. Merging of map values would take time.

Comment: @YashShah It's not about skewed tree but rather about merging of child map values that would take time and space.

Comment: @tusharRawat What is the max value of `N` and `Q`?

Comment: @tusharRawat Can you share a link to the question?

Comment: @vivek_23, I don't know if this question is available in any OJ. I found this problem in a CP book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can actually be done in `O(n log n + q)` using a technique called `small to large` (also sometimes called `DSU on tree` or `sack`).

- First we can read all queries and store in hash table for each node all queries we need to process and their index (so we can output them in order)
- Then we simple to DFS on tree starting from root:

  - Process all children recursively first
  - If its a leaft node, create a new hashTable with value the leaf contains
  - otherwise we take reference to the **largest** hash table of all children of node and add all other children hash table values to it
  - Now we have a hash table of all values in subtree of the node so we can answer all queries in this node in O(1) time using simple look ups

So now some proof why this is actually `O(n log n)` :

- DFS is `O(n)`
- for each hash table we create we will only ever copy it if we find some hash table that is larger than our hash table, so in worst case it will be on hashtables with sizes: `1, 2, 4, 8, 16...` in other words we will copy each hash table into some other hash table at worst `O(log n)` times, there's `O(n)` hash tables in total so in worst case this will take `O(n log n)` time

Of course all this assumes you have a good hash function, if you get too many collisions you can simply use balanced binary search tree instead of hash table to get still good complexity of `O(n log^2 n)`

Comment: so basically we are calculating the query results for each node on it's DFS call() after merging the children hash tables for that node, right?

Comment: @tusharRawat yes